# Adding rows to example table in scenario outline from code in runtime

Tags: c#, selenium, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I have the following feature file. I get a set of values at runtime for batch name and I would like to add the new batch names to example table rows. The number if batch names found at run time varies.

Requirement: Rerun this scenario based on batch names I get during the code executed in BeforeTestRun.

```
Scenario Outline: Verify captured document values against CMS for 
Given user is in QueueHandling home page Dashboard
And user has batches assigned to himself/herself
When user selects "<batchName>" batch from batch list
Then selected batch is opened in a new window
And user views all identified documents
When user selects "Settlement Coversheet" document and compare data
When user selects "AssetLoanAgreement" document and compare data
Given user navigates back to QueueHandling home page Dashboard

Examples: 
| batchName |
| QGOL2B    |
| QGK3UB    |
```

Comment: Add a method to update in 1str feature where you will get the batchnames to update `.feature` file Examples table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you mean is have a separate feature file to update the examples table in the current feature file?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: I thought example data is taken when test suite is compiled. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to take the batch names out of your scenario and to stop using a scenario outline.

Your current scenario is all about HOW the user does something, scenarios should be about what the user is doing. If you take this approach you get simpler clearer scenarios, and you push the HOW down into your step definitions or better yet to helper methods that your step definitions call.

I can only speculate on what you are doing here because your scenario isn't very clear, but hopefully it will be enough to get you started

```
Scenario: User checks their batches
  Given the user has a new set of batches
  When the user checks their batches
  Then ...

# user_batch_checking_steps ---------------------

Given 'user has a new set of batches' do
  @batches = load_batches
end

When 'the user checks their batches' do
  @results = {}
  @batches.each do |batch|
    @results << check_batch(batch: batch)
  end
end


module BatchStepHelper
  def load_batches
    # here is where you make a call to retrieve you list of batches
  end

  def batch(batch: )
    # here is where you do all your interactions to check you batch
```

What this does it take all the programming (the HOW) out of cucumber and pushes it down so it ends up in your programming language where you have the tools to do things like retrieve your list of batches.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @diabolist. I have already thought of this approach. But then representing this in extent report will be a challenge right? Please advice if you know how to incorporate this to the report

Comment: I don't know anything about extent reports. However because all your stuff is taking place in code now, you can pretty much put what you want wherever you want it. You might be able to get stuff in your report by outputting to system.out.